# Java JSON(String) Mapping to another different named JSON

Tags: java, jackson, jaxb, gson, jax-rs

i have String JSON Request like below :

```
{
    "myheader": {
        "source": "1",
        "userid": "1",
        "branch": "123",
        "service": "test",
        "operation": "test"
    },
    "mybody": {
        "rates": {
            "brncode": "12",
            "ccy1": "USD",
            "ccy2": "EUR"
        }
    }
}
```

But i need to map another JSON with different field names before send it to **URL** :

i want below JSON Request which was mapped :

```
{
    "header": {
        "source": "1",
        "userid": "2",
        "branch": "123",
        "service": "1",
        "operation": "2"
    },
    "body": {
        "Rates": {
            "brncode": "123",
            "ccy1": "USD",
            "ccy2": "EUR"
        }
    }
}
```

How to do that ? 
Problem is :

i am using GSON(from.json) to convert string json to object class,

```
_ToSendRequest = gson.fromJson(jsonRequest, ToClass.class);
```

But this class (ToClass.class) requires First JSON FORMAT, header with `"myheader" :`

Comment: Well you could try to parse it into a more generic format e.g. Jackson's `readTree()`. Then you could change the keys and reformat that tree to json.

Comment: could you provide me any example?

Comment: Well, you could have a look at the documentation. It's basically something along those lines: `ObjectNode rootNode = (ObjectNode)objectMapper.readTree(inputJson); rootNode.set("header", rootNode.remove("myheader")); String outputJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(rootNode);` - You might want to play around with this a little and of course add some error handling, e.g. to handle missing elements.

Comment: Thank you thomas, i solved it using @JsonGetter, JsonSetter